# IE8 does not show image in anchor with inline-block display

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I've found strange issue of IE8, when I have `img` in `a` and `a` having `display-inline` CSS value, image is disappeared:

```
<a id="logo" href="/">
  <img src="/poetry-logo-white.png" alt="poetry logo white" width="60" height="74">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  display: inline-block; /* not works */
  display: inline; /* works */
  display: block; /* works */
}
```

If I set `inline` or `block` for `display` in CSS then it works.

If anyone has had same issue before? Why could not it be working with `inline-block`?

I've not tested it in other IE versions anyway.

Comment: Did you try giving it these properties: `a { display: display-inline; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }`?

Comment: Or giving the `img` a `block` `display`? `img { display: block; }`

Comment: And the most important, did you set the `DOCTYPE`?

Comment: I did doctype, but issue is that it will not work only with `inline-block`

Comment: I often encounter this. Do you have max-width on your image and/or the anchor? This can sometimes be the cause for some reason. If you have a max-width on either, try also adding width: 100%.